# How to store a string into an an array?

Tags: c++

I want to store this string into an an array.

space= 0

A,a =1

B, b =2

C , c = 3

. 
.

Z, z= 26

```
 string myArray[26] =
       { "A", "B", "C", "D",”E”,”F”,”G”,”H”,”I”,”J”,”K”,”L”,”M”,”N”,”O”,”P”,
        ”Q”,”R”,”S”,T”,”U”,”V”,W”,X”,”Y”, ”z” };

 for (int i = 0; i < myArray; i++)
 {                 
    myArray[] = myArray[i]  
    cerr << myArray[i] << endl << endl;                  
 }
```

Is that how to get each character with number?

Comment: _'Is that the way in order to get each character with number ?'_ In short: **NO**.

Comment: "*... this string ...*" which one, please?

Comment: I don't want to be rude but I cannot...stop... Oh noes...

Comment: space= 0

A,a =1

B, b =2

C , c = 3

. . 

Z, z= 26

Comment: @EdHeal Of course it does not :-) At the very least, a semicolon is missing after the assignment.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight m- I know it does not - it was more of a statement. Perhaps the username of the poster is correct. The ambition is to just make it compile

Answer (score 2):

What you've got is an array of strings, not an array of characters. A `string` is a container of characters, in the sense that it is capable of holding multiple characters. Your task can be solved with one or two strings, depending on your design preferences (see below).

> A, a =1
>
> B, b =2

You are placing two characters per position. However, `string`s cannot hold more than one character at a single index. If you need both the upper and lower case character to occupy the same spot, you need to make either two strings, or two spots.

Here is the first approach (two strings):

```
string upper = " ABCDEF...";
string lower = " abcdef...";
int pos = ...; // The desired position
cout << upper[pos] << endl;
cout << lower[pos] << endl;
```

Here is the second approach (two positions):

```
string pairs = "  AaBbCcDdEeFf...";
int pos = ...; // The desired position
cout << pairs[2*pos] << endl;   // Upper
cout << pairs[2*pos+1] << endl; // Lower
```

Comment: What u mean by int pos ? what to write their a number of the sequence ?

Comment: @Ambition `pos` is the number in the sequence. When `pos` is zero, you get a space; when `pos` is one, you get an `'A'` or an `'a'`, and so on.